# How to differentiate a multi-word name in the middle of a sentence?

Tags: writing-style, quotation-marks

Let's say you name a project "Going After" or "Respect For". How do you differentiate these names in the middle of a sentence in order to minimize potential confusion?

Do you surround them with quotation marks like what I just did or is there a better way?

For example, I want to say:

> At the start of the Going For series, I worked on....

Is italicizing the text a better approach than surrounding it with quotation marks?

Comment: This just boils down to [“How to punctuate titles](http://allaboutwritingconsulting.com/2013/12/how-to-properly-punctuate-titles-when-to-use-italics-underlining-and-quotation-marks-as-well-as-correct-capitalization/)

Comment: The capitalization will usually be sufficient to indicate that it's a name.

Comment: There's a lot of leeway in this, but for your example, I like the quotation marks.

Comment: Thanks for the good suggestions everyone. I think I will stick with capitalization only, but in cases where capitalization isn't enough, will then resort to quotation marks.